# Getting timeout error in this python while using itertools.permutation ? Please tell me how can i reduce time required by this program execution

Tags: python, algorithm

Yet Another Minimax Problem 
You are given non-negative integers. We define the score for some permutation () of length to be the maximum of  for.

Find the permutation with the minimum possible score and print its score.

Note:  is the exclusive-OR (XOR) operator.

code:

```
# Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT

import itertools
import math
from operator import xor
def per_me(g):
    max =0
    for r in range(0,len(g)-1):
        if(xor(g[r],g[r+1])>max):
            max=(xor(g[r],g[r+1]))
    return max
n = int(raw_input())
arr = raw_input()
l = list(map(int,arr.split(' ')))
p = itertools.permutations(l)
count = 1000000000000
for i in p:
    if(per_me(i)<count):
        count = per_me(i)
print count
```

Input:

```
10
12 0 4 3 1 1 12 3 11 11
```

output:

```
8
```

How can I reduce time required by this code

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/yet-another-minimax-problem/editorial

Comment: this might go better on codereview

Answer (score 0):

Let `i` be the largest natural number such that some but not all of the input numbers have bit `i` set. The minimum score will be the minimum value of `a xor b` where `a` has bit `i` set, and `b` doesn't, and `a` and `b` are in the input list. It's easy to see that the score must be at least this large (since at some point in any permutation there must be a number with bit `i` set next to one without bit `i` set), and any permutation that groups all the inputs with bit `i` set first and the inputs without bit `i` set afterwards and puts the `a` and `b` from above together at the boundary achieves exactly that score (because `a xor b` has `i` as its highest bit, and all other adjacent numbers have highest bit less than `i`).

Even without thinking further, this reduces the problem to an O(n^2) problem, which should be good enough since n <= 3000.

```
def minxor(aa):
    bits = unbits = 0
    for a in aa:
        bits |= a
        unbits |= ~a
    i = bits & unbits
    while i & (i-1):
        i &= i-1
    xs = [a for a in aa if a & i]
    ys = [a for a in aa if (a & i) == 0]
    return min(x ^ y for x in xs for y in ys)

print minxor([1, 2, 3, 4])
print minxor([1, 2, 3])
print minxor([7, 6, 5, 4])
print minxor([12, 0, 4, 3, 1, 1, 12, 3, 11, 11])
```

(Note that in the code, `i` is not quite the same as in the description -- rather than the index of the largest bit that's present in some but not all of the inputs, it's the value of that bit).

One can optimize further by not comparing every `x` and `y` when computing the `min`. That reduces the solution to O(n log n), and one can find the solution even for quite large input lists:

```
def bestpair(xs, ys, i):
    if i == 0:
        return 0
    x0 = [x for x in xs if (x&i)==0]
    x1 = [x for x in xs if x&i]
    y0 = [y for y in ys if (y&i)==0]
    y1 = [y for y in ys if y&i]
    choices = []
    if x0 and y0:
        choices.append(bestpair(x0, y0, i//2))
    if x1 and y1:
        choices.append(bestpair(x1, y1, i//2))
    if choices:
        return min(choices)
    return bestpair(xs, ys, i//2) + i

def minxor(aa):
    bits = unbits = 0
    for a in aa:
        bits |= a
        unbits |= ~a
    i = bits & unbits
    while i & (i-1):
        i &= i-1
    return bestpair([a for a in aa if a & i], [a for a in aa if (a & i)==0], i)

print minxor(range(100000))
```